# In Julia, how do I find out why Dict{String, Any} is Any?

Tags: dictionary, julia, hdf5

I am very new to Julia and mostly code in Python these days.  I am using Julia to work with and manipulate HDF5 files.

So when I get to writing out (`h5write`), I get an error because the data argument is of mixed type and I need to find out why.

The error message says `Array{Dict{String,Any},4}` is what I am trying to pass in, but when I look at the values (and it is a huge structure), I see a lot of `0xff` and values like this.  How do I quickly find why the Any and not a single type?

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly but maybe `unique(typeof.(values(my_dict)))`? This will give you all unique types present in the vals of your dict.

Comment: @NilsGudat I get `DataType[Dict{String,Any}]` from your command.  The question I am asking is why Any if we use `my_dict`?  What is it about my data that makes it apparently of mixed type?

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that you have an Array of dicts - so the `my_dict` in the above should be an element of your Array, i.e. `unique(typeof.(values(my_dict[1])))`. What this might do is tell you what types make up the `Any` - it could be that there are actually mixed types and `Any` is the narrowest common type, or there's only one type and for some reason your `Dict` has not been typed in construction.

Comment: @NilsGudat Think that is what I am after and answers the question I am asking.  `DataType[Array{UInt8,3}, Array{String,1}]`. Now on to the exploration, thanks

Comment: Cool glad that worked - made it an answer so you can close this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to make this an answer:

If `my_dicts` is an `Array{Dict{String, Any}, 4}`, then one way of working out what types are hiding in the `Any` part of the dict is:

```
unique(typeof.(values(my_dicts[1])))
```

To explain:

- `my_dicts[1]` picks out the first element of your Array, i.e. one of your `Dict{String, Any}`
- `values` then extracts the values, which is the `Any` part of the dictionary,
- `typeof.` (notice the dot) broadcasts the `typeof` function over all elements returned by `values`, returning the types of all of these elements; and
- `unique` takes the list of all these types and reduces it to its unique elements, so you'll end up with a list of each separate type contained in the `Any` partof your dictionary.